# Calculating standard deviation across rows

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have the following data:

```
colA <- c("SampA", "SampB", "SampC")
colB <- c(21, 20, 30)
colC <- c(15, 14, 12)
colD <- c(10, 22, 18)
df <- data.frame(colA, colB, colC, colD)
df
#    colA colB colC colD
# 1 SampA   21   15   10
# 2 SampB   20   14   22
# 3 SampC   30   12   18
```

I want to get the row means and standard deviations for the values in columns B-D.

I can calculate the rowMeans as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(., matches("colB|colC|colD")) %>% mutate(rmeans = rowMeans(.))
#   colB colC colD   rmeans
# 1   21   15   10 15.33333
# 2   20   14   22 18.66667
# 3   30   12   18 20.00000
```

But when I try to calculate the standard deviation using `sd()`, it throws up an error.

```
df %>% select(., matches("colB|colC|colD")) %>% mutate(rsds = sapply(., sd(.)))
Error in is.data.frame(x) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

So my question is: how do I calculate the standard deviations here?

Edit: I tried `sapply()` with `sd()` having read the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058054/standard-deviation-on-dataframe-does-not-work).

Additional edit: not necessarily looking for a 'tidy' solution (base R also works just fine).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this ([using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29581612/r-dplyr-mutate-calculating-standard-deviation-for-each-row)), with`rowSds` from the `matrixStats` package,

```
library(dplyr)
library(matrixStats)

columns <- c('colB', 'colC', 'colD')

df %>% 
  mutate(Mean= rowMeans(.[columns]), stdev=rowSds(as.matrix(.[columns])))
```

Returns

```
   colA colB colC colD     Mean    stdev
1 SampA   21   15   10 15.33333 5.507571
2 SampB   20   14   22 18.66667 4.163332
3 SampC   30   12   18 20.00000 9.165151
```

Your data

```
colA <- c("SampA", "SampB", "SampC")
colB <- c(21, 20, 30)
colC <- c(15, 14, 12)
colD <- c(10, 22, 18)
df <- data.frame(colA, colB, colC, colD)
df
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how old/new `dplyr`'s `c_across` functionality is relative to the prior answers on this page, but here's a solution that is almost directly cut and pasted from the documentation for `dplyr::c_across`:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
     mean = mean(c_across(colB:colD)),
     sd = sd(c_across(colB:colD))
  )

# A tibble: 3 x 6
# Rowwise: 
  colA   colB  colC  colD  mean    sd
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 SampA    21    15    10  15.3  5.51
2 SampB    20    14    22  18.7  4.16
3 SampC    30    12    18  20    9.17
```

Comment: This is definitely how I'd do it now. And, I guess `c_across` came out much later? This [post](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/04/dplyr-1-0-0-rowwise/) by Hadley Wickham is from 2020.

Comment: I appreciated this answer for a use case with many columns that I wanted to use in the rowwise calculation. Saved me from typing them all out.

Answer (score 4):

A different `dplyr` and `tidyr` approach could be:

```
df %>% 
 pivot_longer(-1) %>%
 group_by(colA) %>%
 mutate(rsds = sd(value)) %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = "name",
             values_from = "value")

  colA   rsds  colB  colC  colD
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 SampA  5.51    21    15    10
2 SampB  4.16    20    14    22
3 SampC  9.17    30    12    18
```

Or alternatively, using `rowwise()` and `do()`:

```
 df %>% 
 rowwise() %>%
 do(data.frame(., rsds = sd(unlist(.[2:length(.)]))))

  colA   colB  colC  colD  rsds
* <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 SampA    21    15    10  5.51
2 SampB    20    14    22  4.16
3 SampC    30    12    18  9.17
```

Or an option since `dplyr 1.0.0`:

```
df %>% 
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(rsds = sd(c_across(-1)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way using `pmap` to get the rowwise `mean` and `sd`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidur_
f1 <- function(x) tibble(Mean = mean(x), SD = sd(x))
df %>% 
  # select the numeric columns
  select_if(is.numeric) %>%
  # apply the f1 rowwise to get the mean and sd in transmute
  transmute(out = pmap(.,  ~ f1(c(...)))) %>% 
  # unnest the list column
  unnest %>%
  # bind with the original dataset
  bind_cols(df, .)
#   colA colB colC colD     Mean       SD
#1 SampA   21   15   10 15.33333 5.507571
#2 SampB   20   14   22 18.66667 4.163332
#3 SampC   30   12   18 20.00000 9.165151
```

Comment: I'm sure this has probably been asked somewhere (and I can't seem to get an answer from a quick Google search), but what is the significance of `c(...)`?

Comment: @Dunois We are capturing all the row elements with `...` and concatenating (`c`) into a vector

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pmap`, or `rowwise` (or group by `colA`) along with `mutate` :

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(sd = pmap(.[-1], ~sd(c(...)))) # same as transform(df, sd = apply(df[-1],1,sd))
#>    colA colB colC colD       sd
#> 1 SampA   21   15   10 5.507571
#> 2 SampB   20   14   22 4.163332
#> 3 SampC   30   12   18 9.165151

df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(sd = sd(c(colB,colC,colD)))
#> Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   colA   colB  colC  colD    sd
#>   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 SampA    21    15    10  5.51
#> 2 SampB    20    14    22  4.16
#> 3 SampC    30    12    18  9.17

df %>% group_by(colA) %>% mutate(sd = sd(c(colB,colC,colD)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#> # Groups:   colA [3]
#>   colA   colB  colC  colD    sd
#>   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 SampA    21    15    10  5.51
#> 2 SampB    20    14    22  4.16
#> 3 SampC    30    12    18  9.17
```

Comment: I have noticed that for `dplyr` 0.8.3 and `tidyverse` 1.2.1 none of these solutions works with `select`, e.g with `sd(select(.,-colA))` irrespective of using `group_by` or `rowwise`. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you tried but you might have misunderstood the dot insertion rules of magrittr. `df %>% sd(select(.,-colA))` is equivalent to `df %>% sd(., select(.,-colA))`

Comment: So which would be the correct syntax in the case of `select`ing columns (with or without `rowwise()`) prior to the operation?

Comment: Something like `df %>% select(-colA) %>%   mutate(sd = pmap(., ~sd(c(...))))` ?

Comment: Yes, thank you. `pmap` it has to be here. That works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

I see this post is a bit old, but there are some pretty complicated answers so I thought I'd suggest an easier (and faster) approach.

Calculating means of rows is trivial, just use rowMeans:

```
rowMeans(df[, c('colB', 'colC', 'colD')])
```

This is vectorised and very fast.

There is no 'rowSd' function, but it is not hard to write one. Here is my 'rowVars' that I use.

```
rowVars <- function(x, na.rm=F) {
    # Vectorised version of variance filter
    rowSums((x - rowMeans(x, na.rm=na.rm))^2, na.rm=na.rm) / (ncol(x) - 1)
}
```

To calculate sd:

```
sqrt(rowVars(df[, c('colB', 'colC', 'colD')]))
```

Again, vectorised and fast which can be important if the input matrix is large.

Answer (score 2):

Package `magrittr` pipes `%>%` are not a good way to process by rows.
Maybe the following is what you want.

```
df %>% 
  select(-colA) %>%
  t() %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  summarise_all(sd)
#        V1       V2       V3
#1 5.507571 4.163332 9.165151
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I am never sure when to attempt the `tidyverse` approach and when to stick to base R. I should have probably mentioned in the OP that I wasn't necessarily looking for a piped solution?

Comment: @Dunois Maybe yes, but the question is tagged `tidyverse` and pipes are a really nice way to process data. I mentioned it mostly because I tried `rowwise()` and couldn't get it to work and so resorted to `t() %>% as.data.frame()`.

Comment: Here's a way to make `rowwise` work : `df %>% rowwise() %>% summarize(sd = sd(c(colB,colC,colD)))`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper You should post it as an answer.